Warning for string to date conversion in dataframe column (Pandas)
I am completely puzzled.
I have simple df with columns of "kit" and "expiry", imported from Excel. "Expiry" is string in common format "13-SEP-2024". I need to convert column "expiry" of df to date.
Conversion is successful, but I am getting this war
/tmp/ipykernel_51/1454275317.py:4: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

I do not understand why I am getting this warning as I did this type of conversion on another df and I received no warning.
Imported df info is:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   Kit     10 non-null     int64 
 1   Expiry  10 non-null     object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 288.0+ bytes

Data looks like:
    Kit Expiry
0   100322  25-Oct-2024
1   101643  04-May-2025
2   102649  25-Apr-2025
3   107908  22-Sep-2024
4   108386  04-May-2025
5   108710  22-Sep-2024
6   110547  04-May-2025
7   112333  25-Apr-2025
8   115411  22-Sep-2024
9   116434  22-Sep-2024


What is very confusing to me is that following code df["Expiry"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Expiry"]) gives me warning.
But when I create dictionary from pd and get it back to pd with code:
x=df.to_dict()
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)


and then I try df["Expiry"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Expiry"]) I have no warning.
df info after its creation from dict is identical:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 10 entries, 0 to 9
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------  --------------  ----- 
 0   Kit     10 non-null     int64 
 1   Expiry  10 non-null     object
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 240.0+ bytes

Data of df from dict looks identical:

Kit Expiry
0   100322  25-Oct-2024
1   101643  04-May-2025
2   102649  25-Apr-2025
3   107908  22-Sep-2024
4   108386  04-May-2025
5   108710  22-Sep-2024
6   110547  04-May-2025
7   112333  25-Apr-2025
8   115411  22-Sep-2024
9   116434  22-Sep-2024

Can you help me to understand please?

What is your complete code before df["Expiry"]=pd.to_datetime(df["Expiry"]) ?

Looks like you are trying to modify a DataFrame that is a view of another DataFrame as the warning has stated. Please share complete code in the order for review.
